# FPGA applications in power electronics

Tags: power-supply, fpga, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, hdl

I'm a power electronics hardware design engineer and I'm trying to build some additional skills like a sub-branch. I've always been interested in FPGAs and I decided to combine my major skill with my field of interest.

I did some research on FPGA applications in power electronics. I've found some resources, but I see that they're mostly academic because most of the sources are publications, but I intend to work on it in real life applications, maybe commercial products, so I need real-world examples and sources.

I couldn't find a proper source to study.

Does any one know any kind of starting point that I can use to learn about this subject?

Comment: FPGA can be used for control algorithms. Since they have parallel processing abilities, I find it suitable for large and complex power electronics applications such systems in electric vehicles. Multi-core processors that we use today in that kind of applications cost like a FPGA, so I can't see any reason to not use them. More I/O pins, faster processing, safety-critical, can run multi-control loops at the same time...

Comment: FPGA doesnt do anything different than a MCU and DSP for power electronics applications. The only difference is that it can be configured to generate or process different types of signals.  In power electronics, IC's are typically used like power mosfet or IGBT or HBT etc with somewhat higher voltage requirements than a MCU. There are other types of ICs and ASICs too. These are typically controlled with a MCU or with a FPGA or DSP.

Comment: And I'm talking about controlling the power circuitry with FPGA instead of MCU or DSP.... Some time ago we couldn't do that because of the cost issues, but now FPGA's are gettind cheaper and MCU's for complex applications are getting expensive and the last MCU I saw on complex power electronics applcation were more than 100$ price. If I'm going to pay that money, why not to use an FPGA with more I/O pins, faster processing and more reliability.

Comment: FPGA is highly customizable so you kinda get more for the price you pay for a MCU  now that they got cheaper. Definitely yes in your case.

Comment: A site rule: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic*. If you are experienced in your branch of electronics, do you see large swathes of logic circuits that could be "mopped up" by something like an FPGA? I was going to say that you might be looking for an equivalent book to "baking on yachts" but, to my surprise there are sites that focus on this. What do I know LOL.

Comment: @Andyaka The reason you've found sites that focus on baking on yachts are same as I'm searching for this. "People concern about unknown"

Comment: "Buy" word deleted because of site rules.

Comment: A better reason to close might be *opinion based answers*; but I would respond to that by choosing to read it as (or humbly suggest changing the wording to) "what SMPS applications are best solved with an FPGA?" While still a very broad question, it's answerable, and presumably not just by opinion.

Comment: @Andyaka Do I not deserve fresh baked goods on my luxury yacht?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've considered that but calling it only SMPS would be so narrow for FPGA subject and at that time it would be truly "baking on yachts" as Andy said.

Comment: @DasD. Well whatever kind then. I'm guessing by focusing on a digital system, it's not LMPS ("linear mode", not that anyone uses this initialism), so that leaves SMPS. Power electronics, with any kind of efficiency goal, implies class D or other highly nonlinear operating class, is synonymous with SMPS at least in my mind.

Comment: @TimWilliams I know, my ex-manager was calling thyristor based rectifiers as SMPS :)

Comment: Using an FPGA to control something switching at ~1 MHz doesn't make sense.

Comment: The major reason to use an FPGA is the ability to get very fast timing on multiple circuits.  Basically, anything that needs to monitor a lot of voltage/current measurements in parallel.  For example, if you wanted to implement a whole panel of like 32 programmable DC solid state circuit breakers that had fast response time to short circuits that was on the order of a few 10s of us, that would be an application that could benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any book or academic references unfortunately, but I can offer a little experience, and explanation.

---

I led an FPGA based development of a resonant power system, back in 2010-2012 or so.

I will add that a number of decisions were handed down on high, that we were not responsible for (FPGA being one of them; I would've chosen hardware control at the time, with an MCU to manage UI and comms, and nowadays I would probably do it all with an MCU or DSP equipped with suitable timers).

We used a ~25kLUT Cyclone III, 80MSps dual ADC, graphical LCD, and a couple other things (comm ports, etc.).  The external architecture was an inverter driving a series-fed parallel-tuned (LLC, but not quite the same as an "LLC resonant converter", and at much higher Q), with the inverter current and tank voltage being read by the ADC.  The FPGA produced gate pulses directly (high/low side).

The internal architecture was a VCO (DDS type) producing gate pulses with fixed dead time; the frequency value was updated every cycle by a hardware PID controller.  PID inputs included output (tank) voltage, inverter current, phase shift, power, and frequency limits.  Output voltage and current were calculated by taking the RMS of the waveform, a full cycle at a time.  (At least, I think this is what we ended up with -- I led the project, a coworker wrote the VHDL and software; and this was a while ago so I've probably forgotten a few things besides.)  Cycle-based power was measured by multiplying inverter voltage (assumed based on gate signals plus propagation delay) with inverter current then averaging over the cycle, giving a highly responsive but somewhat inaccurate measure; whereas mains power was used to infer output power (less an assumed efficiency figure -- this is a standard method in the business, maybe not ideal but no worse than anyone else) over longer time scales, giving stable output.  The power control thus consisted of a set of registers programming these setpoints, PID parameters and etc.

For UI activities, an ARM soft core was used (also not our decision).  This ran the LCD (parallel bus), comms, managed the power registers, and maybe some slower control loop stuff was offloaded to it too, I don't know.

To be clear, DSP ops were all, I think, done in fixed point.  Registers using extra remainder/accumulator bits as needed for long filter time constants, say.  Probably some floating point was done on the CPU, but that's not a big deal in software regardless (I don't think the soft core came with FPU, but we also might not've had space to use it?).

Oh, in addition to RMS and average, we also did a limited Fourier transform, to get the phase shift more exactly.  More of a sin/cos correlation (and sin/cos are somewhat free because DDS) than a transform, but since we were stuck with the FPGA hardware, yeah, we made use of it.

In the end, the claim, and achievement, was a highly responsive (per-cycle) control, fed at a high sample rate, and solved [largely] in digital hardware (read: FPGA resources).  The reality, of course, was as a PID control, it's no faster than its parameters are set to, which were set conservatively so as to deal with the slowest loads (low frequency and high Q factor) -- and, by physics alone, there simply isn't anything you can do to make a high-Q load start up quickly, so the insistence on quick response was a bit silly (in fact, the "proposal" I was given was 1/4 cycle *or better* per update, which, at least I talked them down a little from that..).

---

As for explanations, I would think applications break down like so:

- Academic research: the chip doesn't exist, so we have to test our novel control somehow.  (It can't stay in *Simulink* forever, right?...)  Digital controls incorporating real-time and perhaps state-space based algorithms will need high sample rates and significant DSP resources (read: vector and matrix ops).  Perhaps those can be relaxed on later optimization, but for research purposes, the power of an FPGA means you don't have to worry about that.
- Commercial application, for which ICs don't exist [yet].  This needn't rely on FPGA, but any programmable platform will do.  This one for example, uses a DSP: [Two Phase Interleaved LLC Resonant Converter Reference Design Using C2000™ MCUs](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-1001)  Reflecting on some features I've seen in newer controllers (e.g. UCC256404), while the core function would be easy enough to solve by a bit of mixed circuitry, the exact way they've implemented it (which they go into fair detail about, actually) clearly depends on highly responsive, either asynchronous or high clock rate (≫10MHz) logic.  Specifically the slew rate logic.  Or maybe it's not as mysterious as it looks, maybe it's just a state machine fed by comparators and timers; but in any case it wouldn't be something you could implement with an MCU, not with the same decision time.
- Uncommon topologies, for which ICs don't exist, probably never will, and which are nonetheless worth the investment to implement.  This more or less fits my experience above, as high-Q resonant applications are fairly limited in quantity, but also quite important industrially.  This probably fits the multiphase LLC above, too, though I would think/hope an ASIC solution comes along eventually.
- Complex topologies, for which the numerous inputs and outputs are important.  There are certain specific applications that have been covered by ICs -- but only when the quantity is justified, and only in those narrow applications.

  Take plasma TVs for example: some panel drivers use quite complex waveforms, requiring multiple bootstrap or isolated gate drivers.  Plasma drivers were pretty quickly integrated, resulting in hybrid or monolithic modules not only incorporating drive circuitry, but IGBTs as well (at least for row/col drivers, with the sustain drivers still using packaged IGBTs).  This is an example of a power electronics application, that isn't a power supply as such, that has fairly high bus width / complexity, though it also has very little feedback (mostly outputs, few inputs).

  The examples you've hinted at in your comments, would also fit into this category.  Lots of monitoring signals, faults, temp limits, input/output voltages and currents, etc.  Now, it happens to be true that many SMPS applications can be reduced to single or few-channel cases, so ICs have still been quite successful.  And you don't gain much by integrating many of those in common: you still need all the control and drive logic per channel.  (Well, maybe you can use a common PID core and mux it between channels, but that's not really saving a lot of logic.)  So there are a lot of things where, there's an array of controllers or regulators, and they're controlled in turn (say by tweaking or forcing the setpoint, or by enable) by something slow, complex and easy-to-use, like an MCU.

There's probably lots of cases or examples I'm missing here, and the above list probably overlaps a lot too, could be trimmed to a tighter categorization perhaps.  I also didn't mention mains inverter or motor control / VFD applications, but those also range from IC based (there are a few dedicated controllers here) to MCUs and DSPs.  Lots of even low end MCUs are integrating timers and logic suitable for half/bridge/BLDC drives.  I don't think there's anything special about solar or battery, at least nothing that can't be solved with an MCU (e.g. MPPT, grid-tie protection rules, charging profiles, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

> I couldn't find a book about FPGA usage on power conversion or any
> online courses.

Not surprising.  Because, at least in my mind, FPGA's are a poor fit for an SMPS type of application.

Have you studied the schematic of a state of the art SMPS to try and find out what exactly there could be replaced with an FPGA?  At it's heart, an SMPS is just a PWM, where the duty cycle is related to the current being drawn from the PS.  The PWM signal in turn is generated by a sawtooth waveform at the switching frequency that is turned into a square wave who's duty cycle is proportional to the output voltage and the desired set point - the error voltage.  That's it!

Then there's a lot of analog circuitry that's wrapped around that basic PWM function.  Things like over voltage and over current protection (analog functions), soft start, under and over input voltage protection, and loop compensation.  All of these are still done in the analog domain.

While in theory you could digitize the parameters of interest (output voltage, current, etc) and implement the control loop as a sampled data system, I'm not sure what benefit this provides.

Proposing an FPGA for an SMPS application seems like a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: There are a great many kinds of SMPS, beyond just those with square pulses and triangular current ramps! First off, the control/management logic (i.e. once you include over/under voltage, temp, startup and reset conditions, etc.) might be worth a small FPGA, or MCU -- if not using an existing IC which contains all this in fixed form. For example, I don't know of any multiphase resonant LLC controller IC; but I have seen applications which were solved using DSPs. Running an LLC can be pretty basic, but with modern features, takes a lot of logic!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't agree and here is the reason: I'm a big fan of analog control on SMPS but in today's world we need SMPS to operated at best, especially with automotive, military or space applications, we call it "Diagnostics". You can pick one of the best SMPS IC in the market and you're going to see it only has a output voltage-current sensing, maybe some temperature protection and input current sensing on it. But we need more, in my last SMPS design I've used all pins of a 64-pin C2000, because I needed sense many currents, voltages, temperature from different points.

Comment: And also I'm now talking about only the SMPS, I said power electronics, which also includes solar applications, motor drives, UPS and others.

Comment: @Tim Williams - So there's another aspect to this, that may be unique to my industry MIL/Aero.  As soon as you talk FPGA or MCU, you fall under our software development processes - very onerous.  Need SRDs, SDPs, and a bunch of other artifacts associated with SW/FW development that you don't have with a traditional analog (mostly) design.  This can drive up development costs significant compared to a couple of op amps and passives used to create the control sections and feedback loops.

Comment: @ Das D. - The application I was describing IS a hi rel, space application.

Comment: @SteveSh That's my point, in many modern cases analog ICs are not capable to do all, that's why we use MCU on most application specific or safety critical SMPS applications. I don't have problem with MCUs but for the last 2-3 years I see that their prices are increasing rapidly (talking about dedicated MCUs) and FPGA prices are decreasing. I thought that if I'm going to pay 50$ for a MCU, I can get a FPGA for it and FPGA has much more pins, much faster processing, probably more reliable.

Comment: @SteveSh Also good reasons, not to mention the low production quantity in that context as well.

Comment: @Das D. - You seemed to have missed my point.  Analog IC's are perfectly capable of meeting the needs for the system I outlined.  We have never used an MCU on a mission critical SMPS application.

Comment: @SteveSh Of course it can meet the needs and they do it perfectly, as I said above I'm a big fan of analog control in SMPS, but I'm talking about the "quantity" of these needs. You could be forced to monitor dozens of voltages and currents. Analog ICs doesn't have that much of pins right? You can use a multiplexer for faults but in this case you can't know where the fault came from so you need more pins in some applications. Diagnostics are forcing us to use digital on SMPSs.